# PDO & Serlialize

Tags: javascript, mysql, serialization, pdo, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with saving/upodating data to my db with PDO.

This function saves my data:

```
    function saveOrder($position,$id) {
    $sql = '
    UPDATE 
        '.DBPREFIX.'section_2 
    SET 
        order = ?
    WHERE 
        id = ?';
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->execute(array($position,$id));
    return var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

This is the sort_2.php:

```
$VAR_BACK = "../";
include($VAR_BACK."_config.php");
include($VAR_BACK."_config_db.php");
include($VAR_BACK."_functions.php");
include($VAR_BACK."_start.php");
include_once("../classes/helper.class.php");
$helper = new helper();

foreach ($_GET['item'] as $position => $item)
{
    $helper->saveOrder($position,$item);
}
```

and this is in my frontend php file:

```
         <script>
// Return a helper with preserved width of cells
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sort tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        update : function () { 
                var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                //$('#info').text(data);
                $("#info").load("sort_2.php?"+data);
            } 
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

and I always get this message:

```
string(178) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order = '2'
    WHERE 
        id = '1'' at line 4"
```

Line 4 is:
order = ?

but I don't know what the error might be here. I tried to cast to (int), I tried stripslashes, nothing worked.

In DB the columns are: id = int(5) and order = varchar(10)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  Quote it in backticks:

```
$sql = '
UPDATE 
    '.DBPREFIX.'section_2 
SET 
    `order` = ?
WHERE 
    id = ?';
```